# How to solve this differential equation of first order (non-linear)?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm stuck on this problem.

$\frac { dy }{ dx } =\frac { 5{ x }^{ 3 }-x{ y }^{ 2 }-2x }{ 3{ x }^{ 2 }y-{ y }^{ 3 } } $

I tried taking **x** common from the numerator and **y** from the denominator and made the substitution

$3{ x }^{ 2 }-{ y }^{ 2 }=t$

After differentiating wrt **x**, I got the following Differential Eqaution

$\frac { dt }{ 4xdx } =\frac { t-{ x }^{ 2 }+1 }{ t } $

I don't know what to do.
Any Suggestions?

Comment: Maybe some substitution which will make it easy to solve.

Comment: this equation is not easy to solve!

Comment: The answer is indeed complicated

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac { dy }{ dx } =\frac { 5{ x }^{ 3 }-x{ y }^{ 2 }-2x }{ 3{ x }^{ 2 }y-{ y }^{ 3 } }$$ is equivalent to $$ x(5{ x }^{ 2 }-{ y }^{ 2 }-2)dx= y( 3{ x }^{ 2 }-{ y}^{ 2 })dy\tag {1} $$ Let $u=x^2$ and $v=y^2$ to transform $(1)$ into $$ (5u-v-2)du+(v-3u)dv=0\tag{2}$$Which is easy to solve.

Comment: Thanks. Now this equation can be converted to homogenous form and solved.

Comment: Exactly! Have a good rest of the day.